# lines visible in screen after entering Login password

Tags: 14.04

i am using Ubuntu 14.04. and i have one problem in it. when i put my login password and enter, horizontal lines as well as dots appear on the upper half of my screen as if screen was not working and then everything resumes well when desktop comes. i have recently installed unity tweak tool to have icon design and hot corners.

can anyone tell me suggestion to get rid of those lines when i login.?

Answer (score 0):

I know. it's a pain those dots.

type in your terminal,

```
sudo xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-grid false
```

you will be asked for the administrator password., that's it. You should not see them in your next login

Source: http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/remove-white-dots-from-login-screen-of.html